# iOS Project Copy Crashes during FirebaseAuth

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, firebase-authentication

So I'm working on a project using flutter in iOS, and I seem to have run into a brick wall.

First, I need to you know I DO have a 100% working copy of the project.  No problems, No bugs, etc.

What I'm trying to do is create a second copy of the project with a few minor changes, and get that to work too.  (Changes like text colour, and name of the app).

I'm using flutter to program this, running FirebaseAuth to authorize the end-user, and google-maps in the project afterwards.

Now after I made those minor changes, I can't seem to get the second project functional at all.  (I've had it functional previously, but that build is lost.  I should have used better source control).

Now I know I had to change the bundle identifier in XCode, which I've done both in the info.plist, and the General Tab of the xcode project.  (Done opening up the workspace, not the project).    Replaced the GoogleServices-Info.plist and added to the project through XCode.  I've also replaced the value for the url scheme in the info.plist with the new value from the GoogleServices-Info.plist.

Also changed the API keys with the new ones I'm supposed to have for the new project.  And made sure all the normal things like ensuring that Push Notifications are active on the project, etc.

So as far as I can remember, I've done everything that I should to get the project to function...  But instead of stalling or giving me errors, it just crashes.

Running through Terminal using the command:

```
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1; flutter run --verbose
```

I get the following error.

```
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:1033/
```

If I run it in Xcode I get the following error:

```
flutter: Phone Auth Verification Failed: Invalid token.
```

and if I run it in VSCode I don't even get that far.

```
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:1025/
```

I checked on their individual git's and issues boards, but I couldn't find anything in flutter or firebase that leads me to any idea as to what is even going on.

Does anyone have something like a checklist of places I could look for possible errors?  (I'm pretty sure it's likely just a setting in XCode I forgot to change, or something like that).  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Project in Xcode then,

Window > Devices & Simulators

1. Select the device and
2. **Uncheck** *Connect Via network*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, that has helped other people, but it does not resolve this error, in this situation.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Not that I have top of my head rn